# Clustering Techniques

Tags: r, clustering, data-mining, k-means

I'm a little new to data mining and would definitely appreciate some tips.
I'm using clustering algorithms looking for possible grouping in some variables described below.
I've been using the Excel data mining add-in which connects to SSAS and uses the EM algorithm by default.  I'm also using R, so far with the Kmeans algorithm.

I have two independent variables X, and G which are integers,
and three dependent variables A, B, C which are related to X and G by the equations below:

$$A=100\left(\frac{2G\cdot.06+K}{2G\cdot.4+2\cdot.06+K+X}\right)$$

$$B=100\left(\frac X{2G\cdot.4+2G\cdot0.06+K+X}\right)$$

C=100-((((2xG)x(0.06)+K)/((2xG)x(.4)+(2xG)x(0.06)+K+X)))x100 + (X/((2xG)x(.4)+(2xG)x(0.06)+K+X))X100)

where K is an arbitrary constant which varies.
Most of the data follows the formulas above with some variation.

I'm using clustering algorithms to look for groupings in the A,B, C variables.
Any advice on strategies for looking for clusters, and how to tell when I've been successful would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra right parenthesis in the formula for C. You'll want to check that formula, and probably also my reformatting of the others. They could be further simplified considerably, but I assumed you had some purpose in not doing so yourself. I mostly removed the unnecessary parentheses, the x between 2 and G, and moved 100 to the front. Revert anything you need to of course.

Comment: You will also want to check the first, as $+2\cdot.06+$ probably is missing a $G$.

Comment: enough research should be done before posting a question.